# Go sqlite3 code stop working after upgrade

Tags: go, sqlite, cgo

I found that my Go sqlite3 code no longer working any more.

For example, here is a simple Go sqlite3 code, [go-sqlite3-test.go](https://github.com/suntong/lang/blob/master/lang/Go/src/db/sqlite/go-sqlite3-test.go), that's been working fine for years. I don't know when it broke, but I'm currently using go1.9.2, and I think the go's version upgrade is the main contribution as I don't recall upgrading any of the dependent go packages of the above code. (**UPDATE:** confirmed from another machine that **go1.8.3** + lastest `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` works just fine. All three machines have `sqlite3` and `libsqlite3-0:amd64` installed).

In one machine, I got:

```
$ go run go-sqlite3-test.go
# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:35:0,
                 from cgo-gcc-prolog:21:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h:24:26: fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory
 # include <linux/errno.h>
                          ^
```

In another machine, using the same go1.9.2, downloading the code into `/tmp/go-sqlite3-test`, I got:

```
$ go run go-sqlite3-test.go 
# pkg-config --cflags sqlite3
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Having installed `pkg-config`, in turn I got:

```
$ go run go-sqlite3-test.go 
# pkg-config --cflags sqlite3
Package sqlite3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sqlite3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sqlite3' found
pkg-config: exit status 1

$ sudo pkg-config --cflags sqlite3 
Package sqlite3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sqlite3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sqlite3' found

$ go build 
# pkg-config --cflags sqlite3
Package sqlite3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sqlite3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sqlite3' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

How to get my Go sqlite3 code working again, for both cases? Thx.

Comment: `go run go-sqlite3-test.go` works for me on `go version go1.8.5 linux/amd64`, `go version go1.9.2 linux/amd64`, and `go version devel +2de98eb8de Sat Dec 16 23:30:58 2017 +0000 linux/amd64`, after `sudo apt install sqlite3 libsqlite3-0` and `go get -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`.

Comment: I also have `gcc` and `libc6-dev` installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @peterSO, after `sudo apt install sqlite3 libsqlite3-0` and `go get -v github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3`, the problem is solved. Do you want to answer, or me deleting this question?